# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n._viewer.saveDocument')- React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdftron

I am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n._viewer.saveDocument') when I click on save button. I think the filepath to save document is not passing inside the overlay. I could be wrong. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```js
render() {
            var filepath;
            if (this.props.dsType == "fileDocument") {
                if (path == fileContent.value) {
                    filepath = path.uri;
                } else {
                    <h1>Unable to render document.</h1>;
                }
            } 
            //value in filepath
            console.info("filepath =", filepath);

            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <DocumentView
                        //ref={(c) => this._viewer = c}
                        document={filepath}
                        onDocumentLoaded={path => {
                            console.info("The document has finished loading:", path);
                        }}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                            <Button
                                onPress={() => {
                                    // Manual Save
                                    this._viewer.saveDocument().then((filePath) => {
                                        console.log('saveDocument:', filePath);
                                      });
                                }}
                                title="Save"
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is this `//ref={(c) => this._viewer = c}` your actual code? Putting comments like that in JSX is hairy already, but this looks like you're never assigning the reference. Also, accessing it is done using `this._viewer.current`

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the suggestion. //ref={(c) => this._viewer = c} - I commented the line in my code since I never used it. Will keep that in mind. But the error is occuring when I press the save button. Do you have any inputs on what might have gone wrong in the onPress event?

Comment: The `ref` line is what makes sure that `this._viewer.current` points to the instance you're later trying to save. You definitely need that. So did you replace `this._viewer.saveDocument()` with `this._viewer.current.saveDocument()`?

Comment: @ChrisG, yes have tried that but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have commented out the line that should assign the viewer instance. As mentioned, that line should be uncommented so that `this._viewer` can be assigned a reference. If you are unsure, you can refer to the example code that is available on GitHub: https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/e19b4970357f9ed2443696eb989f1c91c1905911/example/App.js#L82.